# Trying to load xdp on nic (offloaded)

Tags: python, offloading, xdp-bpf, bcc-bpf

I am trying to load my XDP program directly on the NIC (offloaded XDP).
According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57824120/3716552), I need to specify the device to the following functions:

- `BPF()`
- `load_func()`

I did it like so:

```
b = BPF(src_file=”file.c”, cflags=[”-w”], device=”eno5”)
```

When I added the device I got the following error:

> types.ArgumentError: argument 6: <class ‘TypeError’>: wrong type

Can you please help me to solve this issue and make my XDP program offloaded to the NIC? Thanks

Comment: Does it work as expected without hardware offload?

Comment: Yes it is. When I added the device parameter to BPF function or attach_xdp function, it cause an error

Comment: Could it be that a bug in bcc was introduced at some point? I don't think hardware offload with bcc is tested often. If you don't get an answer here, it might be worth opening an issue on the GitHub repo.

Comment: The type of the device parameter should be the name of the device? In string?

Comment: Yes it should. I tried running the example `./examples/networking/xdp/xdp_drop_count.py` again and it fails with the same error (I don't have access to a SmartNIC anymore, but I would expect [a different error message](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/pull/2502#issuecomment-526731097) for missing offload capailities). I believe this is a bug, although I failed at my quick attempt to bisect (I can't build from older versions on my setup, apparently).